# NodeJS + ExpressJS wait 2 minutes before sending .js files

Tags: node.js, express

I'm having problems loading .js files with my NodeJS project. In this project I'm currently running NodeJS 0.6.15 and Express 2.5.6.

The problem is that when I make a request for a .js file, it takes exactly 2 minutes.

Any idea?!

It's quite strange because it has been working for a long time, and now without changing anything it gets this error. After 2 minutes it returns the files perfectly.

Comment: If you can, please try to do some debugging to simplify your problem down a bit. This is tough to diagnose with no code or idea of how your  requests are dispatched.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you are not calling `response.end()`, so the connection times out in about 2 minutes (typical of HTTP/1.1), gets flushed and closed, and you get your content back in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on Ajax requests instead of .js files. And it turns out that it is caused by the browser itself. By mistake, I installed 32bit Chrome/Firefox in my Windows8 x64 system.

**Issue detail**

The issue is that any Ajax requests with `Content-Type` `application/json` with a small or almost empty response will hang for 2 minutes even though in the Developer Tool you can see the response has returned. And after 2 minutes, the browser marked that request as finished with exact 2 minutes of Content Download in the request's Timing result.

However, this didn't happen for requests with large response. Weird indeed.

**Environment**

- Nodejs v4.2.4 or Nodejs v0.12.9
- Expressjs 4.13.3

Answer (score 0):

```
app.use(session({
    secret: config.secrets.session,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false,
    store: new mongoStore({
    mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection,
      db: 'freport'
    })
 }));
```

set saveUninitialized: false solve the problem, but don't know why yet